# Bullet Point Image alignment Issues in Outlook 2013

Tags: html, outlook, html-table, html-email

I have been creating a HTML Email, tested in litmus which is working and displaying fine in most versions of outlook other than Outlook 2013 where the bullet point images are displaying below the text, here is the code.

```
<table border="0" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0">
  <tr>
    <td valign="top" width="15">
      <img src="https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/dnx-sap-01/324/3/spacer.gif"  height="8" width="15">
    </td>
    <td valign="top" width="12">
      <img src="https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/dnx-sap-01/324/3/BulletGold_Roundtest.jpg" width="7" height="11"/>
    </td>
    <td valign="top" style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color:#222222; font-size:11px;">
      <b>Guide:</b> <a href="http://www.sap.com/">How to get started with Big Data</a>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td valign="top" width="15">
      <img src="https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/dnx-sap-01/324/3/spacer.gif"  height="8" width="15">
    </td>
    <td valign="top" width="12">
      <img src="https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/dnx-sap-01/324/3/BulletGold_Roundtest.jpg" width="7" height="11">
    </td>
    <td valign="top" style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color:#222222; font-size:11px;">
      <b>Benchmarking Assessment Tool:</b> <a href="https://valuemanagement.sap.com/Sapbenchmarking_Portal.html#ID=340" target="_blank">SAP Big Data Maturity Model</a>
    </td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td valign="top" width="15">
      <img src="https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/dnx-sap-01/324/3/spacer.gif"  height="8" width="15">
    </td>
    <td valign="top" width="12">
      <img src="https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/dnx-sap-01/324/3/BulletGold_Roundtest.jpg" width="7" height="11">
    </td>
    <td valign="top" style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color:#222222; font-size:11px;">
      <b>Video Whitepaper:</b> <a href="http://www.sap.com/">Shining a Light on the Value of Big Data</a>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: That's been a while since I've seen "spacer". But OK, this is email, so you're forgiven. Anything to make it work. Anyway, have you tried simply replacing all the `valign="top"` with `valign="bottom"`?

Answer (score 2):

That is strange as it looks like it should work fine...

Maybe try setting the width on your table and all cells so that the total widths all add up to the same. You could also simplify your code by swapping out your rows with something like this:

```
  <tr>
    <td valign="top" align="right" width="27">
      <img src="https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/dnx-sap-01/324/3/BulletGold_Roundtest.jpg" width="7" height="11" style="margin: 0; border: 0; padding: 0; display: block;" />
    </td>
    <td valign="top" width="273" style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color:#222222; font-size:11px;">
      <b>Guide:</b> <a href="http://www.sap.com/">How to get started with Big Data</a>
    </td>
  </tr>
```

You should always use `display:block;` on your images too. See how that goes...

Answer (score 0):

My solution was to get rid of the image altogether and code the image with Unicode character `&bull;` "•" set in your desired color, font size, font weight and padding. It's a lot easier to align text with text, than images with text.

```
<td valign="top" width="12">
  <img src="https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/dnx-sap-01/324/3/BulletGold_Roundtest.jpg" width="7" height="11">
</td>
```

replace with

```
<td valign="top" width="12" style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:13px; font-weight:bold; color:#ffcc33 ; padding:5px 0 0 0;">
  &bull;
</td>
```